# How to enable debug on specific table in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I need to enable debug for specific table in postures sql to capture partition detach automatically in Postgres. so I need to figure it out from which user and machine this logs get detached.

Answer (score 0):

Set the following parameters:

```
# will capture all ALTER TABLE statements
log_statement = 'ddl'
# will make sure that user and client IP address are logged
log_line_prefix = '%m [%p] %u %h '
```